# Javascript fill in the missing ranges (integers)

Tags: javascript

I have a sorted array of objects, each with start and end coordinates, stated relative to a larger range that encompasses all of these coordinates. I would like to create new objects and put them into the array.

### JsFiddle link is at the bottom.

Here's a visual representation:

before:

```
|---------------------------------------|
   |-----|     |----------|   |------|
```

after:

```
|---------------------------------------|
|---|-----|-----|----------|---|------|-|
```

I was trying to use a for loop to find the missing ranges and then splice in the appropriate object as I found them. This creates an infinite loop.

I think that I could feasibly create a temporary array with the filled-in objects, then concatenate that with my original array and sort by start coordinate, but I'd like to do it without having to sort the array again.

### [Here is a link to a jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jgmp30hy/7/)

Comment: Your "before" picture shows gaps in the array. But in your code the input array (called "arr") has no gaps: the Start and End elements don't leave any missing indexes. For example, arr[2] ends at 357 and arr[3] starts at 357. Maybe I'm missing something: could you explain where the gaps are in your sample input array?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I deliberately placed a gap after element 6. See the following from console.log:
`console.log("A feature should be placed ...`

edit: between coordinates 1776 and 1807

Comment: Ah, I didn't look carefully enough. Yes, I see that gap. Thanks, will answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is, you are using splice to "modify" the `subfeatures[]` array, (adding a new element) but at the same time you are looping over that array, that causes infinite loop, I think your logic is good, instead of using splice, it may be easier to just construct a new array

the commented line are the only modification you have to do.(you also have to consider if the last element not ending at the upper limit)

```
    //var newArr=[];
      for (i = 0; i < subfeatures.length - 1; i++) {
        //newArr.push(subfeatures[i]);
        if ( subfeatures[i].end != subfeatures[i+1].start) {
            var feat = {start: subfeatures[i].end, end: subfeatures[i+1].start, type: null};
          console.log("A feature should be placed after the current index: "+i+". This feature would have the starting point: "+subfeatures[i].end+" and the ending point: "+subfeatures[i+1].start); 
          //newArr.push(feat);
        }
      }
//return newArr;
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. So you don't think there's a way to do this in a single step?

Comment: You can do it in a single step but then the code would be slower. When you splice you have to move all the later elements in the array every time you find a gap. But if you construct a new array then you only have to go through each array element once. So it's linear time instead of O(n^2)

Comment: I was about to said that.. thanks Michael

Comment: Thanks. That makes perfect sense. I think I've got it now. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/jgmp30hy/9/) I've created a tmp array for the results of the method, then I combine those with the original array and sort.

Comment: you don't need to sort the array if it is sorted initially, you can push it in the for loop, if there is a gap detected, just add it after.

Comment: Ahh, gotcha. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Splice() is not optimal because you have to move all the later elements in the array every time you find a gap. Here's the solution with a new array that Kossel is suggesting:

```
var newArray = [];
for (i = 0; i < subfeatures.length - 1; i++) {
    newArray.push(subfeatures[i]);
    if ( subfeatures[i].end != subfeatures[i+1].start) {
        var feat = {start: subfeatures[i].end, end: subfeatures[i+1].start, type: null};
        newArray.push(feat);
    }
}
```